# Vimeo video still running on background after minimizing the pop up

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, video, vimeo

I have embedded vimeo video in my site, but when i click outside the pop-up or click the close button of the pop up, the video continues to play in the background.

but i need to stop the video on closing of the pop-up.

```
<div class="nav-watch">
    <a class="arw-link"  data-toggle="modal" data-target=".video-modal" href="#">
        Watch Film  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right"></span>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="modal fade video-modal" id="videomodel" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <button type="button" class="closed" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                    <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/105864353" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anybody help me to stop the video on close?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all,

Finally i got the solution,

There was short lines of jquery which help me out.

```
videoSRC = $('iframe').attr('src');
  $(' button.closed').click(function () {
      $(' iframe').attr('src', videoSRC);
  });

 $('.video-modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
      $(' iframe').attr('src', videoSRC);
 });
```

Also i have made the demo in jsfiddle.

Click here for demo

> [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/userujjwal/fmy2wLtk/1/)

Comment: Sorry, but does not make much sense to me, first of all your `$('button.clocse')` is not clickable, because of wrong positioning and z-index, and secondly what is this suppose to do. The iframe src will always be the same. Well anyway i am out.

Comment: Close button is clickable, and the problem i got in your fiddle is after we click play for first time,video seems to play but stops and we need to play again, but my solution is, after we click play button. it continues to play and stops when click the close button or outside the pop-up, the background video stops. That's the difference. But i am really appreciating your concern to this question. Thanks mate :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Bootstrap Modal you can listen for the `hidden.bs` event, which gets fired when the modal is hidden.

[Bootstrap Modal Events](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events)

> **hidden.bs.modal**
>
> This event is fired when the modal has finished being hidden from the user (will wait for CSS transitions to complete).

Inside the eventhandler you could just clear the iframe `src` attribute like so.

```
$('#videomodel').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $('iframe').attr('src', '');
})
```

To fill the iframe `src` attribute when the modal is being shown you can pass it by using the `data` attribute on the element that triggered the modal.

[Varying modal content based on trigger button](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target)

> Have a bunch of buttons that all trigger the same modal, just with slightly different contents? Use event.relatedTarget and HTML data-* attributes (possibly via jQuery) to vary the contents of the modal depending on which button was clicked. See the Modal Events docs for details on relatedTarget,

```
<a class="arw-link" 
    data-toggle="modal"
    data-target=".video-modal"
    href="#"
    data-video-src="https://your-video-url"> <!-- Video URL goes here!!! -->
    Watch Film  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right"></span>
</a>
```

Then listen for the modal to show and add the value of `data-video-src` to the iframe `src`.

```
$('#videomodel').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
    var videoSrc = button.data('video-src');
    var modal = $(this);
    modal.find('iframe').attr('src', videoSrc);
})
```

---

Here is a [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/fg4cywxh/), since we can't use iframes in SO snippets.

Comment: Great David, your answer was close to the requirement. But not all what i expected. First of all video cannot be played once after it is stopped in your demo. But i need to re run video after it gets stop too. But thanks for your answer.

Comment: Do you mean when the video is being paused?  You can re run the video as many times as you like with the above solution.

Comment: No,i mean the video should stop and when should be able to re run from the beginning

Comment: Did you take a look at the fiddle? I have updated my answer with an example from vimeo. There is no problem with re-running the video from the beginning. Sorry, please do not get me wrong i am just trying to understand what you mean. From the question you posted i would say the fiddle i added is just what you need. And using bootstraps modal events is great for manipulating the content of a modal.

Comment: Thanks mate, you dedicated your time for my solution,although it was not totally same as i was expecting, but was very close to the solution,
Here is the demo i made to my own solution http://jsfiddle.net/userujjwal/fmy2wLtk/

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before. If my memory serves be correctly, the problem occurred on Firefox and maybe IE, but not other browsers.

It depends how your popups work. When you close a popup, does the HTML markup for the popup get removed from the DOM entirely? Check the Elements tab in your console.

Some modal popup systems just hide the popup, but it still exists in the document. Some browsers cannot tell that the video is no longer visible to the user, and so the video keeps playing.

So, to get around the problem, you must make sure that when a popup is "closed" that it is actually completely destroyed and removed from the document entirely, not just hidden.

Comment: Sorry mate,this occurs in all browsers. But in Firefox and IE there was the problem in layout but is solved now. I need to auto stop the video after popup is close. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

you could try one of this.

```
<script src="http://a.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js"></script>
$('.close').click(function() {
    var iframe = $('#vimeo-player')[0];
    var player = $f(iframe);
    player.api('unload');
});
```

vimeo-player is the id of the iframe

or

```
var video = $("#playerid").attr("src");
$("#vimeo-player").attr("src","");
$("#vimeo-player").attr("src",video);
```